# I got Error while creating face recognition code. The Error is " TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src' " what is solution

Tags: python, opencv, video-capture

```
import cv2
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0)
img=video.read()
video2=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("camera",video2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

"HERE IS THE ERROR"
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/D_Ommy/PycharmProjects/Machine_Learning/sampleone.py", line 4, in 
video2=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
TypeError: Expected Ptr<cv::UMat> for argument 'src'
[ WARN:0] global C:\Users\appveyor\AppData\Local\Temp\1\pip-req-build-cff9bdsm\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (435) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback

"""

Comment: Check the doc on [`VideoCapture.read()`](https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/d8/dfe/classcv_1_1VideoCapture.html#a473055e77dd7faa4d26d686226b292c1): By `img = video.read()`, you'll get a tuple `(retval, image)` for `img`, which isn't a valid input for `cvtColor()`.

Answer (score 0):

For this let's go each and every step and what the code is doing.

```
cv2.VideoCapture(0)
```

The `VideoCapture()` on OpenCV returns an object that **can be used** to capture video frame-by-frame (this is not the actual video). Once this object is created, the next step as rightly done should be to read the frames.

```
img=video.read()
```

This OBJECT.read() method returns TWO values instead of one, a boolean flag and the frame. This is what missing here. The correct code for this kind of work could be something as follows.

```
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture('vtest.avi')

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

For details, it's always better to consult the official documentation with code examples.
https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_video_display/py_video_display.html

Answer (score 0):

Add this parameter "cv2.CAP_DSHOW" to the second line of your code :

```
import cv2
video=cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
img=video.read()
video2=cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
cv2.imshow("camera",video2)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```